# How to return the column real value in datatables jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm filling my table using ajax and customizing the return. On column **status** (0 or 1) I used the `"fnRender"` to return a label with **Active** and **Inactive**, but I need to use this same validation to show the button **"Activate"** or **"Deactivate"**, when the script pass on the second validation the `"fnRender"` the status real value was overridden to `"<span class='label label-success'>Ativo</span>"` (or Inactive) and my validation for `"mData" : "id"` that is  `(if(parseInt(oObj.aData['status']) == 1))` doesn't work.

**Possible Solution**

```
if(oObj.aData['status'] == "<span class='label label-success'>Active</span>")
```

The problem is that i don't wanna realize this validation with string, it seems like this is not right.

**Javascript:**

```
var tabela = $('#dynamic-table');

    tabela.dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "minhaURL",
        "aoColumns": [{
            "mData":"nome"
          },
          {
            "mData":"status",
            "bSortable": false,
            "fnRender": function (oObj)                              
            {
                var status;
                if(parseInt(oObj.aData['status']) == 1){
                    status = "<span class='label label-success'>Active</span>"; 
                }else{
                    status = "<span class='label label-danger'>Inactive</span>";
                }
                return status;
            }
          },
          { 
            "mData":"id",    
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": false,
            "fnRender": function (oObj)                              
            {
                var btAtivaDesativa;
                btEditar = "<a href='" + oObj.aData['id'] + "' class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</a>";
                if(parseInt(oObj.aData['status']) == 1){
                    btAtivaDesativa = "<a href='" + oObj.aData['id'] + "' class='btn btn-danger'>Deactivate</a>"; 
                }else{
                    btAtivaDesativa = "<a href='" + oObj.aData['id'] + "' class='btn btn-success'>Activate</a>";
                }
                return btEditar + " " + btAtivaDesativa;
            }
           }
        ] 
    } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
You should use mRender instead of fnRender.

```
    "aoColumns": [{
      "mData": 0,
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        if (data.status == '1') {
          return '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>';
        } else {
          return '<span class="label label-warning">Inactive</span>';
        }
      }
    }, {
      "mData": 1,
      "bSortable": false,
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        if (full[0].status == '1') {
          return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick=edit(' + data.ID + ')>' + 'Edit' + '</a>';
        }
        return '';
      }
    }]
    });
```

mRender has three parameters, in this case I use:

data - for the cell data

type - for nothing

full for the full row array

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IVatjg5yEQGsfasQN8Ea?p=preview) to see how it works

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the same problem is happening, when I check full[5] it return the new value for status is "<span class='label label-success'>Active</span>".

Comment: Of course you shouldn't use the indexes from my Plunker example. This was just some code I had lying around to show you the principle. I tried to change the answer to match your (guessed) data structure more closely. Look at the updated Plunker too.